# Can't get simple cron job to run

Tags: permissions, cron, chown

I have a simple sftp server to exchange files with friends. Whenever someone drops file into it, they're the sole owner of that file and I cannot delete it without using sudo, so I want to run a simple cron job to change all permissions every 5 minutes.

So I start with

```
sudo crontab -e
```

then at the very bottom of the file I add the following

```
5 * * * * /bin/chown myself:sftp_users -R /mnt/sftp/files/
```

I expect the folder owner to be changed to myself:sftp_users every 5 minutes, unfortunately no matter how long I want, nothing happens.

It's probably something silly, but what am I doing wrong?

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

Comment: ext4 and mounted through fstab file. If I run  `/bin/chown myself:sftp_users -R /mnt/sftp/files/` logged in as myself it works as intended

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time specification

```
5 * * * *
```

runs once per hour, at 5 minutes past the hour. To run every five minutes, you would need

```
*/5 * * * *
```